# Vala/SDL Callback for Timer creation

Tags: timer, callback, sdl, vala

I want to refresh my screen every 200ms without having to add some code in a loop.

So, I would like to create a Timer with a callback in Vala using SDL.

I read the documentation but I don't understand what is excpected as a second parameter : http://www.valadoc.org/sdl/SDL.Timer.html

The following code compile without any error :

```
this.timer = new SDL.Timer( 200, () => { this.refresh(); return 0; } );
```

EDIT : here is the full code with SDL :

```
    public View( int width, int height, bool fullscreen, string window_name = "AKITA application" )
        {

            SDL.init( InitFlag.VIDEO | InitFlag.TIMER );

            this.last_tick = 0;
            this.fps = 25; // Set default value for FPS

            uint32 video_flags = SurfaceFlag.DOUBLEBUF | SurfaceFlag.HWACCEL | SurfaceFlag.HWSURFACE;

            this.screen = Screen.set_video_mode( width, height, 32, video_flags);

            if ( this.screen == null )
            {
                stderr.printf ("Could not set video mode.\n");
            }

            WindowManager.set_caption (window_name, "");

            this.timer = new SDL.Timer( 200, () => { this.refresh(); return 0; } );

        }

    public void refresh()
        {
            stdout.printf( "refresh...\n" );
        }
```

But nothing appears (`refresh()` should write something on stdout).

Could someone help me with this (or have a better way to do what I want) ?

Thanks,

Damien

Comment: Did you call `SDL.Init(InitFlag.TIMER)`?

Comment: @haggai_e At first not, but I added it at the beginning as you can see and I have nothing more.

Comment: works correctly here when looping SDL.Event.poll()... using vala master (0.14+)... post a complete test case

Comment: @lethalman Here is the full code : https://bitbucket.org/martindamien/akita/src But I don't use SDL.Event.poll() yet. Is it mandatory to have Timers running ? The file where the problem is : https://bitbucket.org/martindamien/akita/src/ceee8a3b0ceb/src/gfx/View.vala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to run the event loop (e.g. a loop with `SDL.Event.wait()` or `SDL.Event.poll()`), otherwise timers won't get fired.